# How to get specific fields using Schema.DescribeSobjectResult

Tags: apex

I am trying to learn Schema class. I want to get all the field names of any object using Schema.DescribeSobjectResult . Please explain with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code snippet :

```
SObjectType acc = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> allFields = acc.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

From this, you can get all the fields of Account object. you can use similar thing for other objects also.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: it is working. but when i try to get results of all objects it is giving an error. SObjectType acc = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('sObject');

Answer (score 1):

You can query all sobjects by taking all sobjects in a list first, and passing that list in the Schema.describeSObjects function like this :

```
set<string> gl = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().keyset();
list<String> allObjects = new list<String>();
allObjects.addAll(gl);
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(allObjects);
for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res : results) 
{
 map<String, Schema.SObjectField> allFields  = res.fields.getMap();
}
```

Let me know if this helps. Thanks